# Error in the SAP B1 hana query. invalid number: [6930] attribute value is not a number;

Tags: sql, hana

> ERROR: Could not execute 'SELECT T0."DocNum" , T0."Status", T0."CreateDate", T0."U_CardCode", T0."U_CardName", T0."U_RFQNo", ...' in 34 ms 796 µs .
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [339]: invalid number:  [6930] attribute value is not a number;[here]int(jf(isnull("U_Job_No"), ' ', "U_Job_No")) = 8000302, U_Job_No = ''[string] null,docid 1,NDB:

This is my query

```
SELECT T0."DocNum" , T0."Status", T0."CreateDate", T0."U_CardCode", T0."U_CardName", T0."U_RFQNo", T0."U_RFQDate", 
T0."U_RFQTitl", T0."U_InqRefNo", T0."U_Division",T1."DocNum", T1."DocType", T1."DocDate", T1."CardCode", T1."CardName", T1."NumAtCard", 
T1."DocStatus", T1."CANCELED", T1."Comments",T5."DocNum" ,T7."DocNum",T9."DocNum",T3."DocNum"  
FROM "POGLIVEDB"."@INSP_OSINQ"  T0  
LEFT JOIN OQUT T1 ON T0."DocNum" = T1."U_Job_No"
LEFT JOIN QUT1 T2 ON T2."DocEntry"= T1."DocEntry"
LEFT JOIN OPOR T3 ON T3."U_Job_No" = T0."DocNum" 
LEFT JOIN RDR1 T4 on T4."BaseEntry"= T2."DocEntry" and T2."LineNum"=T4."BaseLine" 
LEFT JOIN ORDR T5 on T5."DocEntry"= T4."DocEntry" 
LEFT JOIN DLN1 T6 on T6."BaseEntry"= T4."DocEntry" and T4."LineNum"=T6."BaseLine" 
LEFT JOIN ODLN T7 on T7."DocEntry"= T6."DocEntry" 
LEFT JOIN INV1 T8 on T8."BaseEntry"= T6."DocEntry" and T6."LineNum"=T8."BaseLine" 
LEFT JOIN OINV T9 on T9."DocEntry"= T8."DocEntry"
```

Comment: Initial glance - without access to data - looks to be a data quality issue.   Start by extracting a distinct list of values OQUT.U_Job_No  and checking they are all numbers - SAP DB Tech message suggests otherwise

Answer (score 0):

### SQL to be formated

```sql
--P.s Always organize the indented queries, try this, and verify your type for U_Job_No
SELECT 
    T0."DocNum" ,
    T0."Status", 
    T0."CreateDate", 
    T0."U_CardCode",
    T0."U_CardName",
    T0."U_RFQNo",
    T0."U_RFQDate", 
    T0."U_RFQTitl", 
    T0."U_InqRefNo",
    T0."U_Division",
    T1."DocNum", 
    T1."DocType",
    T1."DocDate",
    T1."CardCode",
    T1."CardName",
    T1."NumAtCard", 
    T1."DocStatus", 
    T1."CANCELED",
    T1."Comments",
    T5."DocNum",
    T7."DocNum",
    T9."DocNum",
    T3."DocNum"  
FROM 
    "POGLIVEDB"."@INSP_OSINQ"  T0  
    LEFT JOIN "OQUT" T1 ON T0."DocNum" = IFNULL(CAST(T1."U_Job_No" AS INTEGER),-1)
    LEFT JOIN "QUT1" T2 ON T2."DocEntry"= T1."DocEntry"
    LEFT JOIN "OPOR" T3 ON IFNULL(CAST(T3."U_Job_No" AS INTEGER),-1)  = T0."DocNum"
    LEFT JOIN "RDR1" T4 on T4."BaseEntry"= T2."DocEntry" and T2."LineNum"=T4."BaseLine" 
    LEFT JOIN "ORDR" T5 on T5."DocEntry"= T4."DocEntry" 
    LEFT JOIN "DLN1" T6 on T6."BaseEntry"= T4."DocEntry" and T4."LineNum"=T6."BaseLine" 
    LEFT JOIN "ODLN" T7 on T7."DocEntry"= T6."DocEntry" 
    LEFT JOIN "INV1" T8 on T8."BaseEntry"= T6."DocEntry" and T6."LineNum"=T8."BaseLine" 
    LEFT JOIN "OINV" T9 on T9."DocEntry"= T8."DocEntry";
```